# Type mismatch when serializing data class

Tags: kotlin

I'm following [this example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/serialization.html) to serialize a data class. When I do so, I get this build error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Data but SerializationStrategy<TypeVariable(T)> was expected
```

Here's my code:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Data(val a: Int, val str: String = "str")

fun main() {
    println(Json.encodeToString(Data(42)))
}
```

Since I am using the @Serializable annotation, shouldn't I have the right data type? How can I serialize the data class?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The function that only requires the value parameter is implemented as an extension function, so you need to add import

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
```

To make it clear: instead of

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
```

you must write

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found that out myself. Documentation should include proper imports.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the wrong `encodeToString()` function. It has to be `kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString`, not the one from `kotlinx.serialization.json.Json`

Comment: You do need the import, but after the import, you can also use `Json.encodeToString()`, as well as `Json{}.encodeToString()`, I believe. Haven't checked, but presumably the import brings in an extension function.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the imports.
The ones below come from kotlin serialization and needs just the string and the object respectively.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
```